# Netbeans and refactoring

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I have Netbeans 7. When I have it generate my getters and setters it does:

```
public void foo() {
}
```

Whereas I need it to do:

```
  public void foo() 
  {
  }
```

Where the starting brace is on the next line.

The same thing happens when I use Source->Format, I need the method brace on the next line.

Is there a way to set this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the main menu bar,

- select `tools` then `options`,
- click on the `editor` icon,
- select the `formatting` tab,
- select `java` on the `language` drop down list
- and select `braces` from the category drop down list.

Then select `new line` for the item `method declaration` in the `braces placement` group.

Answer (score 0):

Tools->Options->Editor->Formatting->Java->Braces